# Qt: Can't set drag mode

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qmainwindow, qtwidgets

I've been stuck on this for a little while now, I'm trying to set the drag mode of my QGraphicsView to `ScrollHandDrag` so that I can build a panning feature on my application.

However whenever I try to set the drag mode Qt always complains that `DragMode` is an undeclared identifier.

I'm also aiming to build a crop functionality (I assume I'd be using rubber band dragging for that?), I'm just wondering why I can't set the drag mode on the View

```
void MainWindow::on_btnCrop_clicked()
{
    cropping = true;
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::CrossCursor);

    // Stuck with this...
    ui->imageView->setDragMode(ScrollHandDrag);
}
```

^ I have tried multiple other workarounds but I've not yet found any solution, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've checked your includes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not `QGraphicsView` specific an issue, but generic C++. Your problem is located at this line:

```
ui->imageView->setDragMode(ScrollHandDrag);
```

The problem is that you assume that you have visibility to the ScrollHandDrag value, whereas it appears inside the `QGraphicsView` scope. Therefore, since you are trying to access that value in your `MainWindow`, you will need add the scope explicitly as follows:

```
ui->imageView->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
```

Note that how even the [documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qgraphicsview.html#DragMode-enum) specifies the scope for this constant:

> QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag 1   The cursor changes into a pointing hand, and dragging the mouse around will scroll the scrolbars. This mode works both in interactive and non-interactive mode.

Here is my minimal building code:

```
#include <QGraphicsView>

int main()
{
    QGraphicsView graphicsView;
    graphicsView.setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT += widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make
```

Comment: I had tried the proposed solution above and it still could not find a reference to ScrollHandDrag, any ideas?  I have the includes set up

Comment: @Alex: It is impossible to tell without an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It is most certainly very strange, I ported the same code to Windows and it compiles fine.  Maybe a problem on Yosemite? but I don't understand why, as it still uses the same compiler and linker :/